# Set scale for bc inside a variable

Tags: bash, bc

I am trying to divide two values in a loop using bc, and I have set that value as a variable. My problem is that I want that value to have 2 decimal places, but I am having trouble getting scale=2 to work while defined inside a variable.

Here is my test file:

```
cat file.txt
Sc0000000_hap1  0   1200    32939
Sc0000000_hap1  1199    2388    28521
Sc0000001_hap1  0   1200    540
```

Here is the loop I am running:

```
while read name start stop sum; do

   divisor=`expr ${stop} - ${start}`
   avg=`scale=2; expr $sum / $divisor | bc ` #I want 2 decimal points here
   echo ${name} ${start} ${stop} ${avg} >> ${outfile}

done < file.txt
```

Here is the output I am getting:

```
Sc0000000_hap1 0 1200 27
Sc0000000_hap1 1199 2388 23
Sc0000001_hap1 0 1200 0
```

Here is the output I want:

```
Sc0000000_hap1 0 1200 27.45
Sc0000000_hap1 1199 2388 23.99
Sc0000001_hap1 0 1200 0.43
```

I have tried a few variations on my syntax but I can't seem to get it to work. Can someone show me how to code this correctly? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```bsh
   avg=`scale=2; expr $sum / $divisor | bc `
```

You are

- setting a *shell* variable `scale` to 2
- calculating the *integer* division using `expr` and passing that value to `bc` (read `man expr`)
- bc does not perform any calculations, it just outputs the number that was fed into it.

Let `bc` do the work:

```bsh
avg=$(echo "scale=2; $sum / ($stop - $start)" | bc)
```

Now bc gets to do the whole calculation, and you set the **bc** scale variable.

---

Braces are not the same as double quotes. Use:

```bsh
   echo "${name} ${start} ${stop} ${avg}" >> ${outfile}
```

---

Use `$(...)` instead of `` `...` ``

Comment: Yes this works perfectly. Thank you for your clarification on this!